# I get an error when I run jsp file: Refers to the missing type error

Tags: java, jsp

When I run my `.jsp` file, I got an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [57] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
The method getAllProducts() from the type ProductDaoImpl refers to the missing type ProductBean
54:     
55:     List<ProductBean> products = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
56:     
57:     products = prodDao.getAllProducts();
58:     
59:     for(ProductBean product : products){
60:
```

Here is my index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="adrian.dao.*,adrian.beans.*,java.util.*,javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream,java.io.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Ellison Electronics</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/changes.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <%
    /* Checking the user credentials */
        String userName = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
        String password = (String)session.getAttribute("password");
        String userType = (String)session.getAttribute("usertype");
    
        boolean isValidUser = true;
        
        if(userType == null || userName == null || password==null || !userType.equals("customer")){
    
            isValidUser = false;
        }   
        
    %>


<%
    if(isValidUser) {
%>
<%@ include file="userHeader.html" %>

<%
    }
    else{
%>
<%@ include file="header.html" %>
<%
    }
%>

<!-- Start of Product Items List -->
<div class="products" style="background-color: #E6F9E6;">
<div class="row text-center" >

  <%
  
    ProductDaoImpl prodDao = new ProductDaoImpl(); 
    
    List<ProductBean> products = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();  <----------- here is my error
    
    products = prodDao.getAllProducts();
    
    for(ProductBean product : products){
    
        String addToCartUrl = null;
        String buyNowUrl = null;
        
        if(isValidUser){
            addToCartUrl = "./AddtoCart?uid="+userName+"&pid="+product.getProdId()+"";
            buyNowUrl = "./BuyNow?uid="+userName+"&pid="+product.getProdId()+"";
        }
        else{
            addToCartUrl = "login.html";
            buyNowUrl = "login.html";
        }
        
  %>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="./ShowImage?pid=<%=product.getProdId() %>" alt="Product" style="height:200px; max-width:200px; max-width:300px;">
      <p class="productname"><%=product.getProdName() %> ( <%=product.getProdId() %> ) </p>
      <p class="productinfo"><%=product.getProdInfo() %></p>
      <p class="price">Rs <%=product.getProdPrice() %> </p>
      <form method="post">
        <button type="submit" formaction="<%= addToCartUrl%>">Add to Cart</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" formaction="<%= buyNowUrl%>">Buy Now</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <%
  
    }
  
  %>
  
  
</div>
</div>
<!-- ENd of Product Items List -->


<%@ include file="footer.html" %>

</body>
</html>
```

ProductDaoImpl.java

```
package adrian.dao;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adrian.beans.ProductBean;
import adrian.beans.DemandBean;
import adrian.utility.DBUtil;
import adrian.utility.IDUtil;
import adrian.utility.MailMessage;

public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao{

    @Override
    public String addProduct(String prodName, String prodType, String prodInfo, double prodPrice, int prodQuantity,
            InputStream prodImage) {
        String status = null;
        String prodId = IDUtil.generateId();
        
        ProductBean product = new ProductBean(prodId, prodName, prodType, prodInfo, prodPrice, prodQuantity, prodImage);
        
        
        status = addProduct(product);
        
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String addProduct(ProductBean product) {
        String status = "Product Registration Failed!";
        
        if(product.getProdId()==null)
            product.setProdId(IDUtil.generateId());
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into product values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
            ps.setString(1, product.getProdId());
            ps.setString(2, product.getProdName());
            ps.setString(3, product.getProdType());
            ps.setString(4, product.getProdInfo());
            ps.setDouble(5, product.getProdPrice());
            ps.setInt(6,product.getProdQuantity());
            ps.setBlob(7, product.getProdImage());
            
            int k = ps.executeUpdate();
            
            if(k>0) {
            
                status = "Product Added Successfully with Product Id: "+product.getProdId(); 

            }
            else {
                
                status = "Product Updation Failed!";
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            status = "Error: "+e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String removeProduct(String prodId) {
        String status = "Product Removal Failed!";
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from product where pid=?");
            ps.setString(1, prodId);
            
            int k = ps.executeUpdate();
            
            if(k>0) {
                status = "Product Removed Successfully!";
            
            
                ps2 = con.prepareStatement("delete from usercart where prodid=?");
                
                ps2.setString(1, prodId);
                
                ps2.executeUpdate();
            
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            status = "Error: "+e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps2);
        
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String updateProduct(ProductBean prevProduct, ProductBean updatedProduct) {
        String status = "Product Updation Failed!";
        
        if(!prevProduct.getProdId().equals(updatedProduct.getProdId())) {
            
            status = "Both Products are Different, Updation Failed!";
            
            return status;
        }
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("update product set pname=?,ptype=?,pinfo=?,pprice=?,pquantity=?,image=? where pid=?");
            
            ps.setString(1, updatedProduct.getProdName());
            ps.setString(2, updatedProduct.getProdType());
            ps.setString(3, updatedProduct.getProdInfo());
            ps.setDouble(4, updatedProduct.getProdPrice());
            ps.setInt(5, updatedProduct.getProdQuantity());
            ps.setBlob(6, updatedProduct.getProdImage());
            ps.setString(7, prevProduct.getProdId());
            
            int k = ps.executeUpdate();
            
            if(k>0)
                status = "Product Updated Successfully!";
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String updateProductPrice(String prodId, double updatedPrice) {
        String status = "Price Updation Failed!";
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("update product set pprice=? where pid=?");
            
            ps.setDouble(1, updatedPrice);
            ps.setString(2, prodId);
            
            int k = ps.executeUpdate();
            
            if(k>0)
                status = "Price Updated Successfully!";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            status = "Error: "+e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductBean> getAllProducts() {
        List<ProductBean> products = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from product");
            
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                
                ProductBean product = new ProductBean();
                
                product.setProdId(rs.getString(1));
                product.setProdName(rs.getString(2));
                product.setProdType(rs.getString(3));
                product.setProdInfo(rs.getString(4));
                product.setProdPrice(rs.getDouble(5));
                product.setProdQuantity(rs.getInt(6));
                product.setProdImage(rs.getAsciiStream(7));
                
                products.add(product);
                
            }
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(rs);
        
        return products;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getImage(String prodId) {
        byte[] image = null;
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select image from product where  pid=?");
            
            ps.setString(1, prodId);
            
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next())
                image = rs.getBytes("image");
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(rs);
        
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductBean getProductDetails(String prodId) {
        ProductBean product = null;
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from product where pid=?");
            
            ps.setString(1, prodId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()) {
                product = new ProductBean();
                product.setProdId(rs.getString(1));
                product.setProdName(rs.getString(2));
                product.setProdType(rs.getString(3));
                product.setProdInfo(rs.getString(4));
                product.setProdPrice(rs.getDouble(5));
                product.setProdQuantity(rs.getInt(6));
                product.setProdImage(rs.getAsciiStream(7));
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        
        return product;
    }

    @Override
    public String updateProductWithoutImage(String prevProductId, ProductBean updatedProduct) {
        String status = "Product Updation Failed!";
        
        if(!prevProductId.equals(updatedProduct.getProdId())) {
            
            status = "Both Products are Different, Updation Failed!";
            
            return status;
        }
        
        /*System.out.println("pId: "+updatedProduct.getProdId());
        System.out.println("pName: "+updatedProduct.getProdName());
        System.out.println("pType: "+updatedProduct.getProdType());
        System.out.println("pInfo: "+updatedProduct.getProdInfo());
        System.out.println("pPrice: "+updatedProduct.getProdPrice());
        System.out.println("pQuantity: "+updatedProduct.getProdQuantity());*/
        
        int prevQuantity = new ProductDaoImpl().getProductQuantity(prevProductId);
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("update product set pname=?,ptype=?,pinfo=?,pprice=?,pquantity=? where pid=?");
            
            ps.setString(1, updatedProduct.getProdName());
            ps.setString(2, updatedProduct.getProdType());
            ps.setString(3, updatedProduct.getProdInfo());
            ps.setDouble(4, updatedProduct.getProdPrice());
            ps.setInt(5, updatedProduct.getProdQuantity());
            ps.setString(6, prevProductId);
            
            int k = ps.executeUpdate();
            //System.out.println("prevQuantity: "+prevQuantity);
            if((k>0) && (prevQuantity < updatedProduct.getProdQuantity())) {
                status = "Product Updated Successfully!";
                //System.out.println("updated!");
                List<DemandBean> demandList = new DemandDaoImpl().haveDemanded(prevProductId);
                
                for(DemandBean demand : demandList) {
                    
                    String userFName = new UserDaoImpl().getFName(demand.getUserName());
                    
                    MailMessage.productAvailableNow(demand.getUserName(), userFName, updatedProduct.getProdName(), prevProductId);
                    
                    boolean flag = new DemandDaoImpl().removeProduct(demand.getUserName(), prevProductId);
                    
                    if(flag)
                        status += " And Mail Send to the customers who were waiting for this product!";
                }
            }
            else if(k>0)
                status = "Product Updated Successfully!";
            else
                status = "Product Not available in the store!";
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        //System.out.println("Prod Update status : "+status);
        
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public double getProductPrice(String prodId) {
        double price = 0;
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from product where pid=?");
            
            ps.setString(1, prodId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()) {
                price = rs.getDouble("pprice");
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sellNProduct(String prodId,int n) {
        boolean flag = false;
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try {
            
            ps = con.prepareStatement("update product set pquantity=(pquantity - ?) where pid=?");
            
            ps.setInt(1, n);
            
            ps.setString(2, prodId);
            
            int k = ps.executeUpdate();
            
            if(k>0)
                flag = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            flag = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        
        return flag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getProductQuantity(String prodId) {
        
        int quantity=0;
        
        Connection con = DBUtil.provideConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from product where pid=?");
            
            ps.setString(1, prodId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()) {
                quantity = rs.getInt("pquantity");
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        DBUtil.closeConnection(con);
        DBUtil.closeConnection(ps);
        
        return quantity;
    }

}
```

ProductBean.java

```
package adrian.beans;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ProductBean implements Serializable{
    
    public ProductBean() {}
    
    private String prodId;
    private String prodName;
    private String prodType;
    private String prodInfo;
    private double prodPrice;
    private int prodQuantity;
    private InputStream prodImage;
    
    
    public ProductBean(String prodId, String prodName, String prodType, String prodInfo, double prodPrice,
            int prodQuantity, InputStream prodImage) {
        super();
        this.prodId = prodId;
        this.prodName = prodName;
        this.prodType = prodType;
        this.prodInfo = prodInfo;
        this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
        this.prodQuantity = prodQuantity;
        this.prodImage = prodImage;
    }
    public String getProdId() {
        return prodId;
    }
    public void setProdId(String prodId) {
        this.prodId = prodId;
    }
    public String getProdName() {
        return prodName;
    }
    public void setProdName(String prodName) {
        this.prodName = prodName;
    }
    public String getProdType() {
        return prodType;
    }
    public void setProdType(String prodType) {
        this.prodType = prodType;
    }
    public String getProdInfo() {
        return prodInfo;
    }
    public void setProdInfo(String prodInfo) {
        this.prodInfo = prodInfo;
    }
    public double getProdPrice() {
        return prodPrice;
    }
    public void setProdPrice(double prodPrice) {
        this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
    }
    public int getProdQuantity() {
        return prodQuantity;
    }
    public void setProdQuantity(int prodQuantity) {
        this.prodQuantity = prodQuantity;
    }
    public InputStream getProdImage() {
        return prodImage;
    }
    public void setProdImage(InputStream prodImage) {
        this.prodImage = prodImage;
    }
    
}
```

Can somebody help me with this error?

Comment: Consider using Expression Language instead of the deprecated scripplets.

Comment: Isn't `An error occurred at line: [57] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp] The method getAllProducts() from the type ProductDaoImpl refers to the missing type ProductBean` good hint?